# Get a struct's field names

Tags: reflection, racket, metaprogramming

In Racket, I want to use a struct's field names for metaprogramming.

For example:

```rkt
(struct pt [x y])
(struct-fields pt) ;; -> '(x y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t. You can get the accessors, which here would be `pt-x` and `pt-y`, but you can’t get just `x` and `y` alone. Why is this? Well, one reason is that there could actually be duplicates. Consider a scenario involving some pernicious struct subtyping:

```
#lang racket/base

(struct A [x] #:transparent)
(struct B A [x] #:transparent)
```

Now a structure of type `B` has two `x` fields, `A-x` and `B-x`. For this reason, any macro that tries to use field names alone with structs is broken when subtyping may be involved.

What you *can* do is use the accessors, instead, which you can achieve by using `syntax-local-value` plus `extract-struct-info`, then looking at the fourth element of the resulting list. However, honestly, I think that’s too much work, so I wrote a syntax class to do all the hard work for you. Install the `syntax-classes` package and use the [`struct-id`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax-classes/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse%2Fclass%2Fstruct-id..rkt%29._struct-id%29%29) syntax class:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base
                     syntax/parse/class/struct-id)
         syntax/parse/define)

(define-simple-macro (struct-accessors id:struct-id)
  (list id.accessor-id ...))

> (struct pt [x y] #:transparent)
> (struct-accessors pt)
'(#<procedure:pt-x> #<procedure:pt-y>)
```

Comment: I suppose I could call `~a` on the accessor procedure then extract the field name from the string representation, but this seems extremely inelegant. I was hoping to use struct field names to extract values to instantiate structs with from a sxml document, but I'm starting to think this isn't the best way, or even an acceptable way to do it.

Comment: @Winny The `accessor-id` attribute gives you the ids, so you could just use `(map syntax-e (attribute accessor-id))` to get a bunch of symbols; don’t use `~a` for that in such a hacky way. Stripping a common prefix off *would* work for structs without subtyping, so that would be okay iff you ensure `supertype-id` is `#t`.